# Jquery if/else redirect showing the "else" value when an "if" is true

Tags: jquery, redirect, if-statement, textbox

I have a jquery `if/else` written that checks the value of a `textbox` and if is equal to a word(s) it will redirect to a `url` - else it changes the value of the `textbox` to "`try again`".  What is happening is when the if value is `true` and the redirect happens, I can see the else value pop up quickly in the textbox before the redirect happens.

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#passphrase').focus();
    $('#passphrase').keyup(function(e) {

        if (e.which === 13) {

            if ($('#passphrase').val() == "marina heights") {
                window.location = "marina heights/index.html";
            }

            else {
                $('#passphrase').val("try again");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you try to simply put a `return;` after the `window.location` line?

Comment: works for me. do you have anything else that is getting called after this? maybe another document.ready that is working on it??

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I'm totally puzzled**

After posting my answer below, I can see in your question **another code** than the one I answered to! And I can't see any "edit" mention though. Don't understand what happened meantime...

Here is the original code I had to work with, exactly reproduced:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#passphrase').focus();
    $('#passphrase').keyup(function(e) {

if (e.which === 13) {

if ($('#passphrase').val() == "marina heights") {
    window.location = "marina heights/index.html";
}
if ($('#passphrase').val() == "BRI") {
    window.location = "http://www.google.com";
}
else {
    $('#passphrase').val("try again");
}
}
});
});
```

---

This is strictly normal, at least when you typed "marina heights".

Because for this first `if` you didn't placed any `else`, so it continues with code under it: before the browser achieve to render what comes from the new `window.location` it had time enough to execute the next `if`, which is not true and leads to display "try again".

This doesn't happen when you type "BRI".

I suggest you simply use `switch()` for this kind of problem, especially as chances exist the final real example has more than 2 known locations.

Thus also you have the benefit of not duplicating jQuery work for `$('#passphrase').val()`.

So you may write something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var location='',
        passphrase = $('#passphrase');
    passphrase[0].focus();
    passphrase.keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            switch(passphrase.val()) {
                case "marina heights":
                    location = "marina heights/index.html";
                    break;
                case "BRI":
                    location = "http://www.google.com";
                    break;
                default:
                    passphrase.val("try again");
                    return false;
            }
            window.location = location;
        }
    });
});
```